# Creating a map that can be accessed by multiple clients

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have created an asynchronous TCP server (local) which accepts multiple clients. I have created a map class where client can set a value pair, retrieve it and delete it. My question is how can I make this map class accessible to all clients i.e. only one copy of this map class is created when the server initializes and all the clients can add/modify values in that one class so that anything that has been added or modified is visible to all clients?

Thanks in advance
P.S. I am a beginner in C++ so maybe I'm missing a very basic concept.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? From your description, this is already exactly what you are doing.

Comment: A little explanation of how the server is implemented and initialized and some code snippets would help in answering your question.

Comment: Actually, when multiple clients are connected, both initiates the map classes of their own i.e. one client who can add the value in the map is not  retrievable by the other client.....only the client who has added the value is able to retrieve that value.

Comment: @MartinClarke initialize the map on the server side. There is only a single server right?

Comment: exactly, there is only one server but when Client A sets a value, only he is able to retrieve it, and when client B sets a value, only he can retrieve it, not client A
Let me add some code/diagrams to better explain my question.

Comment: Oh I guess I'm initializing the map after accepting the connections, maybe that's what creates the problem

Comment: Try [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html)